# @JsonNaming not working with lombok builder

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, lombok, builder

I am having below class

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Test {

    String tTObj;
    String value;

    public String gettTObj() {
        return tTObj;
    }

    public void settTObj(final String tTObj) {
        this.tTObj = tTObj;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String json = "{\"TTObj\" : \"hi\", \"Value\": \"hello\"}";

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final Test test = objectMapper.readValue(json, Test.class);

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Above one is working fine and able to deserialize.

But if I use lombok builder for deserialization, it's failing.

Below is class with lombok builder used for deserialization

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Test.Builder.class)
@Value
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with", builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Test {

    String tTObj;
    String value;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String json = "{\"TTObj\" : \"hi\", \"Value\": \"hello\"}";

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final Test test = objectMapper.readValue(json, Test.class);

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

got below error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "TTObj" (class com.demo.Test$Builder), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "value", "ttobj"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"TTObj" : "hi", "Value": "hello"}"; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.demo.Test$Builder["TTObj"])
```

How to deserialize  `"{"TTObj" : "hi", "Value": "hello"}"` this using @JsonNaming with lombok builder?

Comment: Which lombok version are you using?

Comment: plugins {
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.1.0'
}

Comment: Please don't name your field `tTObj`. That's an utterly useless identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson annotations on the class have to be also present on the builder class to have an effect on deserialization. Automatic copying of `@JsonNaming` to the builder class was introduced with Lombok 1.18.14.

However, the `io.freefair.lombok` Gradle plugin in version 5.1.0 uses Lombok version 1.18.12 as default. So that's one version too old (Lombok uses only even numbers as minor/patch level numbers).

You could use a newer version of the Gradle plugin, or [configure it manually to use a newer Lombok version](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/5.1.0/reference/#_lombok_plugins) via `build.gradle`:

```
lombok {
    version = "1.18.20"
}
```

PS: With Lombok >= 1.18.14, you may consider using [`@Jacksonized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) instead of manually configuring your builder:

```java
@Value
@Jacksonized
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Test {
    ...
}
```

You don't need the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation and the "with" prefix in that case.